# Java ambiguous method call

Tags: java, spring, lombok

the code is here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/orderDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String orderDetail(Model model, @ModelAttribute("order") Order order, @RequestParam(value="orderId", required=false, defaultValue = "-1") int orderId) {
        Store store = storeRepo.findByName(EMarketApp.STORE_NAME).get(0);
        if (orderId >= 0 &&
                (!(store.getOrderList().isEmpty()))) {
            // modify
            Order o2 = store.getOrderList().stream().filter(o -> (((Order) o).getId() == orderId)).findAny().get();
            order.setId(o2.getId());
            order.setItems(o2.getItems());
            order.setDateOrdered(o2.getDateOrdered());

            //get the cost of the products ...

            Double cost =0.0;
            for(Item item: order.getItems()){
                cost+=item.getPrice() * item.getAmount();
            }
            model.addAttribute("orderCost", cost);

        }
        return "form/orderDetail";
    }
```

it says ambiguous method call on :

```
order.setId(o2.getId());
order.setItems(o2.getItems());
order.setDateOrdered(o2.getDateOrdered());
```

but i don t understand, the order and o2 are two separate Objects, then why is it saying that it is ambiguous ...

Please Help ...

the class Orders ...

```
@Entity (name = "orders")
public @Data
class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "orderID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "orderDate", nullable = false)
    private String dateOrdered;

    public Order() {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show all signatures of the `setId`, `setItems`, `setDateOrdered` methods?

Comment: Why are you modifying the parameter object? Did you intent this method to have side-effects?

Comment: Using lombok ... Andrew

Comment: @DanyalAhmedChaudhry, where did you exactly get the exception?

Comment: You have no `@Getter` or `@Setter` annotations

Comment: @cricket_007, he uses the `@Data` instead, which means including getters and setters as well

Comment: cricket_007: sorry mate, did not really understand what you want to say ... about Why are you modifying the parameter object? Did you intent this method to have side-effects?

Comment: @DanyalAhmedChaudhry, copy and paste the stacktrace you got, please

Comment: `Order order` is a parameter. `order.setId(o2.getId());` is modifying said parameter. I do not see the purpose of copy `o2` into `order`. That is my point. Like, you should do `for(Item item: o2.getItems())`. You should not need to set any values onto `order`

Comment: where did you exactly get the exception? – Andrew Tobilko
I am not getting the exception, it is underlining the method [o2.getItems()] and is not compiling ...

Comment: @DanyalAhmedChaudhry, try to compile and show a compile error then

Comment: It seems to be a problem of integration of your IDE and lombok.